# Div not appearing on Webpage

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner programmer and I'm practicing Website layouts with CSS3 but one of my div's isn't showing up.

The div **#right-rectangle** isn't appearing and I'm not sure why because there is a width, height, and background color. I've checked the code on validators but it's not showing anything about the div.

```css
    #rectangle-1 {
     width: 31%;
     height: 20vh;
     background-color: #D0021B;
     float: left;
     margin: 2vh;
    }
    
    #rectangle-2 {
     width: 31%;
     height: 20vh;
     background-color: #4A90E2;
     float: left;
     margin: 2vh;
     
    }
    
    #rectangle-3 {
     width: 31%;
     height: 20vh;
     background-color: #4A4A4A;
     float: left;
     margin: 2vh;
    
    }
    
    .paragraph {
     margin-left: 2vh;
     margin-right: 2vh;
     float: left;
    }
    
    p { 
        word-spacing: 5px;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    
    #left-rectangle {
     height: 30vh;
     width: 33%;
     float: left;
     background-color: #D0021B;
     margin: 2vh;
    }
    
    #right-rectangele {
     height: 30vh;
     width: 60%;
     background-color: #4A90E2;
     float: left;
     margin: 2vh;
    }
    
    #bottom-left-rectangle {
     height: 20vh;
     width: 65%;
     background-color: #4A90E2;
     float: left;
     clear: both;
     margin: 1vh 0vh 0vh 2vh;
    }
    
    #bottom-right-rectangle {
     height: 20vh;
     width: 32%;
     background-color: #D0021B;
     float: left;
     margin: 1vh 2vh 0vh 0vh;
    }
    
    #rect-inside-rect {
     height: 20vh;
     width: 75%;
     background-color: #4A4A4A;
     margin: 0vh 0vh 0vh 7.5vh;
    }
```

```html
<head>
    
      <title>HTML Layout 1-b</title>
    
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css"/>
    
      <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <meta name ="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      
    
     </head>
    
     <body>
    
      <div id = "container">
       <div id = "top">
        <div id = "rectangle-1"></div>
        <div id = "rectangle-2"></div>
        <div id = "rectangle-3"></div>
       </div>
    
       <div class = "paragraph" id = "paragraph-1">
        <p> Nunc at velit quis lectus nonummy eleifend. Curabitur eros. Aenean ligula dolor, gravida auctor, auctor et, suscipit in, erat. Sed malesuada, enim ut congue pharetra, massa elit convallis pede, ornare scelerisque libero neque ut neque. In at libero. Curabitur molestie. Sed vel neque. Proin et dolor ac ipsum elementum malesuada. Praesent id orci. Donec hendrerit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aenean sit amet arcu a turpis posuere pretium. Nunc at velit quis lectus nonummy eleifend. Curabitur eros. Aenean ligula dolor, gravida auctor, auctor et, suscipit in, erat. Sed malesuada, enim ut congue pharetra, massa elit convallis pede, ornare scelerisque libero neque ut neque. In at libero. </p>
       </div>
       
       <div class = "paragraph">
        <p> Nunc at velit quis lectus nonummy eleifend. Curabitur eros. Aenean ligula dolor, gravida auctor, auctor et, suscipit in, erat. Sed malesuada, enim ut congue pharetra, massa elit convallis pede, ornare scelerisque libero neque ut neque. In at libero. Curabitur molestie. Sed vel neque. Proin et dolor ac ipsum elementum malesuada. Praesent id orci. Donec hendrerit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aenean sit amet arcu a turpis posuere pretium. Nunc at velit quis lectus nonummy eleifend. Curabitur eros. Aenean ligula dolor, gravida auctor, auctor et, suscipit in, erat.  </p>
       </div>
    
       <div id = "left-rectangle"></div>
       <div id = "right-rectangle"></div>
    
       <div id = "bottom-left-rectangle"></div>
       <div id = "bottom-right-rectangle">
        <div id = "rect-inside-rect"></div>
       </div>
    
    
      </div>
     </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

it's a typo: replace "#right-rectangele" with "#right-rectangle" :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your css rule:

```
#right-rectangele
```

instead of

```
#right-rectangle
```